# Authorization in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm new to laravel, I'm building an API and using laravel sanctum to implement authorization. After authorization, I get the user token, but I can't get any other user data so that I can, for example, extract the ID of the authorized user or substitute it in another table from the database, or use the data of the authorized user in any way. I don't know what exactly I did wrong. Please help me solve this problem. Here is my code:

AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\DocBlock\Tags\Uses;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserCreateRequest $request){
        $user               = new User();
        $user->login        = $request->get('login');
        $user->password     = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $user->email        = $request->get('email');
        $user->number_phone = $request->get('number_phone');
//        $user->role_id      = 1;
        $user->assignRole('user');

        if (!$user->save()) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Регистрация не удалась']);
        }

        return response()->json(['message'=>$user->jsonSerialize()]);
    }

    public function auth(UserLoginRequest $request){

        $user = User::query()->where('login', $request->get('login'))->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Попытка входа не удалась'], 400);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
        $user->api_token = $token;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['message'=>$user->api_token = $token], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы вышли из системы'], 200);
    }
}
```

Api.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('test', function () {
        return view('test');
    });
});

Route::post('auth', [AuthController::class, 'auth']);
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('authLogout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('application/{id}', [ApplicationController::class, 'showById']);
Route::get('application', [ApplicationController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('applicationStore', [ApplicationController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('applicationDelete', [ApplicationController::class, 'delete']);

Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [UserController::class, 'delete']);
Route::post('userStore', [UserController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('review', [ReviewController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('reviewStore', [ReviewController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('review/{id}', [ReviewController::class, 'update']);
```

UserLoginRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserLoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

Kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: What data do you want to get

Comment: User ID and username

Comment: You want to get the logged-in username ane and id

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// Get the currently authenticated user...

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

// Get the currently authenticated user name...

```
$username = Auth::user()->name;
```

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

in blade.php you can get it like this

```
{{{ isset(Auth::user()->name) ? Auth::user()->name : Auth::user()->id }}}
```

Comment: Together with the token, I tried to return Auth:: user (), but got this response: "message": [
        "10|KsqRXX085nRZ5PNjwbxvt0IchNjby3wjFusWvdwi",
        null
    ]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,I figured it out